# Health & Fitness Data Aggregator

Tags: open-source, monitoring, health, fitness, etl

I would like to be able to collect my health and fitness data from multiple sources. I would then like to standardize the format of the data using some standard (OpenmHealth?). Once transformed that data would be stored somewhere either locally, or in some public cloud storage where it can be retried later when needed.

The solution should be user focused and not medical professionals (though they could certainly benefit from the data as well though sharing). I am well aware of GNUHealth and OpenMhealth, but neither of these appears to be focused on the individual users but rather health professionals.

The problem I have is that I have data in multiple applications, none of them speak with one another and so I have a lot of data silos. On top of that, many of the services I use are cloud services so I don't actually have full access to my data. Another problem is that there is not real reason to depend on cloud solutions for the collection of personally generated health and fitness data. To top all of that off, I have lost data many times due to the cloud provider outages or, in the case of an offline app, the developer made changes to the data structure and I lost 2 years of monitoring.

Does anything like this exist in the FOSS/FLOSS/FLO world? If not, why?

I can easily imagine an entire ecosystem of health applications with this at the core. Imagine  being able to send personally collected data to your doctor using some open protocol like ActivityPub.

Anyway, if anyone knows of something like this, please let me know.

Comment: It would help if you would list all of your data sources. "I don't actually have full access to my data" sounds like a blocker, but check for an APi. Worst case, copy paste from the screen, or scrape the website, or even OCR a screenshot. I am fairly certain that no such thing exists, and that data gathering would be tedious, even one-off, never mind regularly, although perhaps it could be automated. It might be easier to look for apps that play well together, even at the expense of some functionality. Good luck